# Accidentally rm -rf /lib64

Tags: shell, centos

I accidentally removed /lib64 from the remote server.

The system is CentOS 6.8 64bit.

And then the basic command like ls are not found.

How can I recover the system?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Restore from a backup, and stop using the `root` user routinely in the future.

Comment: If only there were a way to save important files somewhere for recovery later on. This would allow you to back up to a previous point in time where things were working. I may just try to patent this idea of "back up" and earn some serious money in licencing fees :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d suggest restoring from a Backup.

Failing that; build a BackupPC server and make sure you always have active backups.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

you  are able to login to the server you  can copy /lib64 from any working server with same operating system with same version.